# nested iterator errors

Tags: c++, iterator

```
//arrayList.h
template<class T>
class arrayList{
public:
    // constructor, copy constructor and destructor
    arrayList(int initialCapacity = 10);
    arrayList(const arrayList<T>&);
    ~arrayList();
    // iterators to start and end of list
    class iterator;
    class seamlessPointer;
    seamlessPointer begin();
    seamlessPointer end() ;
    protected:
        T* position;
    }; // end of iterator class

protected:
    T* element;
    int arrayLength; 
    int listSize; 
};


//main.cpp


int main() {
```

...........

```
    sort(dict.begin, dict.end(),compare_nocase); ////
    return 0;
}
```

Two errors are:

```
..\src\test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\src\test.cpp:50:44: error: no matching function for call to 'sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>, arrayList<std::basic_string<char> >::seamlessPointer, bool (&)(std::string, std::string))'

..\src\/arrayList.h: In member function 'arrayList<T>::seamlessPointer arrayList<T>::end() [with T = std::basic_string<char>]':
..\src\test.cpp:50:28:   instantiated from here
..\src\/arrayList.h:114:3: error: 'arrayList<T>::seamlessPointer::seamlessPointer(T*) [with T = std::basic_string<char>]' is private
..\src\/arrayList.h:49:44: error: within this context
```

Why do I get these errors?

**EDIT**

The problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that one of the problems is that you've written

```
sort(dict.begin, dict.end(),compare_nocase);
```

instead of

```
sort(dict.begin(), dict.end(),compare_nocase);
```

(Notice the parentheses after `dict.begin`)

Without compiling the code myself I'm not sure if there's anything else lurking here.  I'll keep looking and update this answer if I find anything else.

***EDIT:*** I noticed that your `seamlessPointer` class doesn't mark any of its member functions `public`, which would make any use of them a compile-time error.  That's probably at least partly responsible for the other errors you're getting.

Comment: most errors are related to : 'arrayList<T>::seamlessPointer& arrayList<T>::seamlessPointer::operator+(int) [with T = std::basic_string<char>, arrayList<T>::seamlessPointer = arrayList<std::basic_string<char> >::seamlessPointer]' is private

Comment: @Sean- Updated with another fix.  Can you check this?

Answer (score 2):

For the second error, it would look like you've just omitted the `public:` access specifier from your seamlessPointer class. Remember that class members in C++ are private by default so none of its constructors or member functions are accessible to the rest of your code.